# Composer test branch install

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have made a test branch to test some composer installations:

https://github.com/Sangoku/laravel4-idehelper-generator/tree/compabilityTest

Now I want to install via Composer this changed branch on my Laravel project, but I don't know how I could tell composer to pull my version of the code.

I don't know Composer enough to tell it which branch he should pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your composer.json and:

require the package

```
"require": {
            ...
    "jonphipps/idehelper": "dev-master"
},
```

And set the repository for it to be downloaded from

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "https://github.com/Sangoku/laravel4-idehelper-generator.git"
    }
],
```